# ie8 showing social media icons strangely

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer

Helping out a friend with this website to make it ie8 friendly, I am not really familiar with all of ie8's quirks.

I have fixed most of the problems.

Still having a problem with the social media icons, there is a weird google plus at the very top left of the page that should not be there. The social media icons for each post are all out of line.

Also haven't been able to get the search button to go to the right of the search box.

http://blog.staples.ca/

Comment: This isnt only a IE issue the element is actually there in all browsers only IE for some reason is rendering the called iframe howerver.

Comment: If you [validate that page](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.staples.ca%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), there are a number of omitted end tags for images. That may be a start for fixing layout issues.

Comment: Note that as well as the social media icon issue, in IE9 and IE8, the entire layout is not centered as it is in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend moving this script to be in with the other social media links and not at the top of the document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js" gapi_processed="true"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings, somewhere along advanced it should say along the sorts "restart Browser settings". I do not use Internet Explorer, due to the quirk it could leave gaps for computer compromises especially with a hefty anti-virus. I recommend Google Chrome, if the problem continually persists.

Comment: I wish we could convince everyone to switch to proper modern browsers but the fact is people don't. Which is why I am trying to make this site still compatible with ie8...

Comment: I don't think that recommending Google Chrome is a solution to a requirement to make IE8 friendly.  Well coded CSS shouldn't result in considerable difference across browsers.